# Jenkins Pipeline - How to checkout two repos from different SCM (svn and git) in the same folder, and prevent the last one from wiping the first one

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline, jenkins-git-plugin

I have a project that have both git and svn (git for devs, svn for artists)
Both repos have the same folder hierarchy. .svn and .git folders are in the same folder.

I try to setup a jenkins pipeline with two 'checkout' that would both checkouts in the same folder but that doesn't seem to work. As far as I understand the issue here, if the checkout (SubversionSCM or gitscm) finds out that there is no repo here (checking .svn/.git folder depending on the SCM used?), the checkout plugin ensures that the checkout folder is empty and wipes it :(.

Therefore, no matter how I reorder things, the second checkout (either gitscm or SubversionSCM) will wipe out the first checkout. How can I prevent that from happening?

Here is the jenkins pipeline repro script I have so far:

```
pipeline
{
    agent any
    stages
    {
        stage('Checkout')
        {
            steps
            {
                checkout changelog: false,
                        poll: false,
                        scm: [ 
                            $class: 'SubversionSCM',
                            additionalCredentials: [], 
                            excludedCommitMessages: '', 
                            excludedRegions: '', 
                            excludedRevprop: '', 
                            excludedUsers: '', 
                            filterChangelog: false, 
                            ignoreDirPropChanges: false, 
                            includedRegions: '', 
                            locations: [[
                                cancelProcessOnExternalsFail: true, 
                                credentialsId: 'svn_credentials', 
                                depthOption: 'infinity', 
                                ignoreExternalsOption: true, 
                                local: '.', 
                                remote: 'http://svn_repo_address']], 
                            quietOperation: true, 
                            workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']]
                            
                checkout changelog: false, 
                        poll: false, 
                        scm: scmGit(branches: [[name: 'develop']], 
                                    extensions: [], 
                                    userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'git_credentials', 
                                                        url: 'http://git_repo_address.git']])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing of described here sounds right. For this to work you need gitignore that will include everything related to svn, and vice versa. I assume none on this is straightforward. Why not just have to neighboring folders: one with git, and the other with svn?

Comment: Regarding issue itself: I assume subsets of files stored in svn and in git aren't intersecting. Just checkout svn in folder1, git in folder2, and then copy one into another manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Subsets of files do intersect! That's the main purpose of our workflow. Using the best free solution of dev world SCM (Git) and the less expensive of artistt world SCM (SVN) in a single Unity project.
Each will have their own packages. Dev keeps control of the project settings by ignoring those in SVN, etc.

Comment: I edited the question because it does not apply only to the workspace root folder. If you use any folder as target for both SCMs checkouts, the last will crunch the the first.

Answer (score 0):

After checking out the SVN or Git repository, you could stash+delete or rename the .svn or .git directory before checking out the remaining repository.

If you needed to make commits later, you could unstash the deleted directory.